# How to extract the base type (name) of a parametric type in Julia?

Tags: julia

Sometimes it would be helpful to have access to the non-parametrized version of a type. E.g. if I have some `foo::Foo{A,B}` it would be nice to have something like `basetype(foo::Foo{args...}) = Foo`. Does Julia provide something like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use `Base.typename` with a parametric type. It returns the *type name* in the form of `Core.TypeName` and you can extract the type using its `wrapper` field.

```
julia> Base.typename(typeof([1])).wrapper
Array

julia> Base.typename(Array{Int64, 1}).wrapper
Array
```

You may also directly retrieve this information with `T.name.wrapper` which *might* be better optimized by Julia, although it does not sound like a good idea. See the relevant issue [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/30430).

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a string/symbol representation, you can also use:

```
julia> nameof(Array{Int64, 1}
:Array

julia>nameof(Foo{A,B})
:Foo
```